# UITextField RightView image goes out of bounds

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield

SO I have a textfield which is basically [JVFloatLabeledTextField](https://github.com/jverdi/JVFloatLabeledTextField) for floating texts and works upon checking if the username is available. If the webservice returns a response object that username already exists the textfields rightview sets a red alert image whereas if it returns that the username is available then the rightview imageview is set to something green.. Well the image is being set a bit out of bounds. I have tried everything.. Attached herewith is the snapshot, and here is the code:

```
    usernameTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    let imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))

    var imageName:String = ""

    if jsonReturned["errorCode"] == "Success" {
        imageName = "isAcceptedIcon"
    } else {
        imageName = "isRejectedIcon"
    }

    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    imageView.image = image
    usernameTextField.rightView = imageView
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I want to shift the image to a bit left. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: try setting imageView mode to scaleAspectFit

Comment: @noob its same.. no effect whatsoever!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO I kind of solved it on my own. Its kind of very simple infact. Instead of appointing to the `rightView`, the imageView.. I had to set rightView's frame and then `addSubview(imageView)` to it. Here's the code and the new attached picture:

```
    userEmailTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    let imageView = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))

    usernameTextField.rightView?.frame = AppManager.shared.CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 20)

    var imageName:String = ""
    if jsonReturned["errorCode"] == "Success" {
        imageName = "isAcceptedIcon"
    } else {
        imageName = "isRejectedIcon"
    }

    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    usernameTextField.rightView?.addSubview(imageView)
```

So yeah that was a tremendous fix! Hope this helps someone else too :)

[image]